# Reuse groups from htaccess Condition

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to get the domain of a website into my RewriteUrl, but I somehow can't get it to work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.(test|com)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(thisdomain|thatdomain) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.%2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

AFAIK, The `%2` should contain the domain, but this redirects to `www.example./`, no extention.
I've also tried this without the 2nd condition, to no avail. Anyone who can see the mistake?

*I start a fresh session each change, the .htaccess is not cached, tested this.*

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(this|that) [NC]` condition?

Comment: This is 1/3rd of the actual code. They have a `this.com` and a `that.com` which follow after this (which never get triggered, no problems from that)

Comment: Yes I can already see many problems in this but just want to understand the requirements better. It would be better if you show all the htaccess content with some clear set of requirements.

Comment: Do you want to avoid matching `this.example.com` and `this.example.com` with this condition?

Comment: nope, all domains are prefixed with `www.`

Comment: The actual code isn't bad at all btw, it works quite cleaverly and fixes a lot of problems :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67838/discussion-between-anubhava-and-martijn).

Comment: No, I am not saying your entire code is bad :) It is just that rule shown in question isn't correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to capture value you need to make sure that condition executes first. Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|this|that) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.(test|com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NE,L]
```

You can not capture a group when you use `!`, therefor your `%2` has no value. You can take it as a seperate Condition to use it.